# Запятая перед «или»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или

Пожалуйста, подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед "или"? И, если можно, какое здесь правило работает?

"Вы в любой момент можете оказаться рядом с беспризорником, который заведет с вами беседу, **или** вы с ним".

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, Лариса! Первое: в шапке Вы спрашиваете о двух запятых (перед "который" и перед "или"), а в тексте собственно вопроса — только об одной (перед "или"). Какая же формулировка правильна? Второе: точка ставится *после* кавычек.

Comment: Если выразить мысль приемлемо: «Вы в любой момент можете оказаться рядом с беспризорником, который заведет с вами беседу, или с которым начнёте говорить вы». «Очень корявой» концовке никакой знак не поможет.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы (и прошу прощения за неточно сформулированный вопрос).  Я поняла, по какому правилу запятую перед "или" в данном случае необходимо оставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы поставила **запятую**:

*Вы в любой момент можете оказаться рядом с беспризорником, который заведет с вами беседу, **или вы с ним.***

Дело в том, что структура предложения **не соответствует** наличию двух однородных определительных придаточных. В первом придаточном предложении беспризорник обозначен союзным словом ***который,*** а во втором ― личным местоимением ***с ним***. Поэтому здесь нет однородных определительных придаточных, правило **об отсутствии запятой нельзя применить.**

А вот **запятую можно поставить**, если мы будем считать "или вы с ним" присоединительной конструкцией, так как союз **ИЛИ** в частных случаях может быть присоединительным. И тогда предложение выглядит вполне нормально (корявым не кажется).

**Примеры предложений** с присоединительным союзом ИЛИ: Он вернулся в одиннадцать часов, ИЛИ около этого. И детей оставили, ИЛИ почти что оставили, в покое. Розенталь § 24. Присоединительные конструкции (пункт 1) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Comment: Поддержу Ваш ответ с удовольствием. Только, считаю, надо поправить неточность: *так как союз **И** в частных случаях может быть присоединительным.*

Comment: Римма, большое спасибо за поддержку и правку!

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

Запятая перед "который" обязательно нужна.
А вот фраза "или вы с ним" очень коряво звучит. Но если принципиально её сохранить, то я бы рекомендовал поставить перед "или вы с ним" вместо запятой длинное тире. Оно даст нужную интонацию.
Ещё как вариант можно запятую заменить на три точки. "с вами беседу... или вы с ним". Это обозначит неожиданность мысли и кое-как компенсирует корявость фразы.

Дополнение. Что касается правила постановки запятой перед "или", то оно в большинстве случаев просто. Если "или" соединяет однородные члены предложения, то запятая не ставится (быть или не быть), а если "или" соединяет, например, две грамматические основы, то запятая необходима. В вашем случае есть два неполных предложения, разделённых запятой. Первое предложение "Беспризорник заведёт беседу с вами", а второе предложение "Вы заведёте беседу с беспризорником". Само собой, что эти фразы нуждаются в разделяющем их знаке препинания.

Comment: Спасибо большое! К сожалению, принципиально оставить именно такую формулировку. Но сторонний корректор настаивает, что запятую перед "или" нужно убрать. Не подскажите, каким правилом необходимо оперировать, чтобы доказать ему правомерность данной запятой? Спасибо!

Comment: Дополнил свой ответ для вас

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемая Лариса! Думаю, Ваш "сторонний корректор" прав, ибо в представленном Вами предложении есть два однородных придаточных предложения, одно из которых является неполным. Известно (Д.Розенталь об этом пишет), что если они соединяются союзами "и" или "или", то запятая между ними не ставится.

Comment: Спасибо, Виктор! Действительно, если это так, то отсутствие запятой имеет основание. Лично мне иногда бывает сложно определить, являются ли предложения однородными придаточными. Может быть, Вы могли бы подсказать, на что следует ориентироваться, чтобы раз и навсегда четко научиться их определять?

Comment: Уважаемая Лариса! Напоминаю Вам, что однородные придаточные предложения  отвечают на один и тот же вопрос и относятся к одному и том же главному предложению. Например: Я знаю, что ты меня любишь и что я тебя тоже люблю. Я знаю - главное предложение. Затем идет первое придаточное: что ты меня любишь. И снова: Я знаю, затем второе придаточное предложение , отвечающее на тот же вопрос: что? что я знаю? что я тебя тоже люблю. В учебниках для 9 класса этот раздел называется "сложноподчиненные предложения с двумя или несколькими придаточными"